# Unity - error CS0117: 'Advertisement' does not contain a definition for 'Initialise'

Tags: unity3d

вот сам код  ошибка вот такая (Assets\script\1-10\hero2.cs(29,45): error CS0117: 'Advertisement' does not contain a definition for 'Initialise')

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using UnityEngine.Advertisements;



public class hero2 : MonoBehaviour
{
   public Joystick joystick;
   private Rigidbody2D rb;
    private bool faceRight = true;
Animator anim;
private float moveInput;
public float jumpForce;
private bool isGrounded;
public Transform feetPos;
public float checkRadius;
public LayerMask whatIsGround;
[SerializeField] private AudioSource jumpSound;
[SerializeField] private AudioSource deadSound;


    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ();
anim = GetComponent<Animator> ();
Advertisement.Initialise("4073998", false);
    }

    
    void Update()
    {
float verticalMove = joystick.Vertical;
isGrounded = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(feetPos.position, checkRadius, whatIsGround);
if (moveInput == 0)
{anim.SetInteger("popka",1);}
else{
Flip();
anim.SetInteger("popka",2);}
if (isGrounded == false){
anim.SetInteger("popka",3);}

}


public void OnJumpButtonDown(){
if (isGrounded == true){
rb.velocity = Vector2.up * jumpForce;
jumpSound.Play();
}

}

void Flip(){
if(moveInput < 0)
    transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0,180,0);
if(moveInput > 0)
    transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0,0,0);

}
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D shit){
if(Advertisement.IsReady())
{
Advertisement.Show("Interstitial_Android");
}
 if (shit.gameObject.tag == "dead"){
     Invoke("ReloadFuckingLevel", 0);

deadSound.Play();
}


}
void ReloadFuckingLevel(){
   Application.LoadLevel (Application.loadedLevel );
}
void FixedUpdate(){
moveInput = joystick.Horizontal;
rb.velocity = new Vector2 (moveInput * 4f, rb.velocity.y );
}

void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D shit){
if (shit.gameObject.tag == "Finish"){
Application.LoadLevel ("Scene");}
}
}
```

Пытаюсь создать первую игру, осталось только рекламу добавить - не получается.

Comment: ¿А без рекламы слабо?

Comment: хотелось бы маленькую копеечку то получить.Захламлять игру рекламой я не собираюсь.

Comment: У меня такой-же трабл - только у меня с проверкой по условию "IsReady". Тоже пишет, что такого метода нет.

Answer (score 0):

все нашел ошибку) initialize а не initialise если кому интересно)